# How to "highlight a row" in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hi i know that "SHIFT + spacebar" 'highlights' an excel row. But what I want to do is actually to 'highlight' it such that the background is yellow. Is there a keyboard shortcut for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can just click on the row number so that the entire row is selected.Now just go to the fill color option, choose your desired color, and the entire row will be highlighted.

Comment: yeah i was asking for a keyboard shortcut if there's one. i do know how to use the ribbon!

Comment: @MEOWER You need to edit your question to clarify you only want a keyboard shortcut. Otherwise, Alison answered what you asked.

Answer (score 3):

i'm looking for a shortcut also. the only method I found so far is the F4 button. it mimics your last action.

So I would suggest: 
highlight with color the row you want, and select another row you want to highlight with the same color and press F4.

Comment: Use Alt+H+H and choose color or use the arrow for color then use F4

Answer (score 0):

You click the little paint bucket icon in the ribbon, in the Font section.  There is a little arrow next to it which gives you an option to change the colour.

[image: paint bucket icon]

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on any Office program, small key-symbols appear on the ribbon tabs. If you press one of those keys, more symbols appear on that tab's buttons. Those symbols denote the shortcuts for the buttons. So, each shortcut consists of three key presses *after each other*:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>
2. The tab's shortcut key.
3. The button's shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut to select highlight in excel 2013 for windows is Alt H + H (hold down ALT and tap H twice). Probably works on other versions with the ribbon.

This works well for highlighting rows too, just use the shortcut to select a row in Excel - Shift + Space Bar, followed by the highlight shortcut (Alt + H + H)